# Add hue category labels in seaborn stripplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have two DataFrames that I am plotting as a stripplot. I am able to plot them pretty much as I wish, but I would like to know if it is possible to add the category labels for the "hue".

The plot currently looks like this:

[image: Example plot.]

However, I would like to add the labels of the categories (there are only two of them) to each "column" for each letter. So that it looks something like this:

[image]

The DataFrames look like this (although these are just edited snippets):

```
     Case Letter Size Weight
0   upper      A   20   bold
1   upper      A   23   bold
2   lower      A   61   bold
3   lower      A   62   bold
4   upper      A   78   bold
5   upper      A   95   bold
6   upper      B   23   bold
7   upper      B   40   bold
8   lower      B   47   bold
9   upper      B   59   bold
10  upper      B   61   bold
11  upper      B   99   bold
12  lower      C   23   bold
13  upper      D   23   bold
14  upper      D   66   bold
15  lower      D   99   bold
16  upper      E    5   bold
17  upper      E   20   bold
18  upper      E   21   bold
19  upper      E   22   bold
```

...and...

```
     Case Letter Size  Weight
0   upper      A    4  normal
1   upper      A    6  normal
2   upper      A    7  normal
3   upper      A    8  normal
4   upper      A    9  normal
5   upper      A   12  normal
6   upper      A   25  normal
7   upper      A   26  normal
8   upper      A   38  normal
9   upper      A   42  normal
10  lower      A   43  normal
11  lower      A   57  normal
12  lower      A   90  normal
13  upper      B    4  normal
14  lower      B    6  normal
15  upper      B    8  normal
16  upper      B    9  normal
17  upper      B   12  normal
18  upper      B   21  normal
19  lower      B   25  normal
```

The relevant code I have is:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 7.5))
plt.tight_layout()

sns.stripplot(x=new_df_normal['Letter'], y=new_df_normal['Size'], 
              hue=new_df_normal['Case'], jitter=False, dodge=True, 
              size=8, ax=ax, marker='D',
              palette={'upper': 'red', 'lower': 'red'})

plt.setp(ax.get_legend().get_texts(), fontsize='16') # for legend text
plt.setp(ax.get_legend().get_title(), fontsize='18') # for legend title

ax.set_xlabel("Letter", fontsize=20)
ax.set_ylabel("Size", fontsize=20)
ax.set_ylim(0, 105)
ax.tick_params(labelsize=20)

ax2 = ax.twinx()

sns.stripplot(x=new_df_bold['Letter'], y=new_df_bold['Size'], 
              hue=new_df_bold['Case'], jitter=False, dodge=True, 
              size=8, ax=ax2, marker='D',
              palette={'upper': 'green', 'lower': 'green'})

ax.legend_.remove()
ax2.legend_.remove()

ax2.set_xlabel("", fontsize=20)
ax2.set_ylabel("", fontsize=20)
ax2.set_ylim(0, 105)
ax2.tick_params(labelsize=20)
```

Is it possible to add those category labels ("bold" and "normal") for each column?

Answer (score 1):

Using seaborn’s scatter plot you could access to the `style` (or even `size`) parameter. But you might not end up with your intended layout in the end. [scatterplot documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html#seaborn.scatterplot).

Or you could use the `catplot` and play with rows and columns. [seaborn doc for catplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html#seaborn.catplot)

Unfortunately Seaborn does not natively provide what you are looking for : another level of nesting beyond the `hue` parameter in `stripplot` (see [stripplot documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.stripplot.html). Some seaborn tickets are opened that might be related, eg [this ticket](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/1673). But I’ve come accros some similar feature requests in seaborn that were refused, see [this ticket](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/1287)

One last possibility is to dive into the matplotlib primitives to manipulate your seaborn diagram (since seaborn is just on top of matplotlib). Needless to say it would require a lot of effort, and might end-up nullifying seaborn in the first place ;)

Answer (score 1):

Set `dodge=True` enables this:

```
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

sns.violinplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="smoker",
               data=tips, palette="muted")

sns.stripplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="smoker",
               data=tips, palette="muted", dodge=True)
```

[image]

**EDIT:**
And with the `df` provided by the OP:

```
df = pd.read_csv('./ongenz.tsv', sep='\t')

sns.stripplot(x=df['Letter'], y=df['Size'], data=df, hue=df['Case'], dodge=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I already have `dodge=True` in my code, so maybe there's something else...?

Comment: Yes I noticed that, but in this minimal examples it's really ```dodge=True``` that does the trick. I edited my post by including the ```df``` you provided. Works the same. Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I see there has been some confusion. I managed to generate the same plot as you, but I was hoping to generate the second plot in my example, which has an extra level of labelling (bold/normal) under the letter labels (A, B, C, D, E). Thanks.